# Using camera zoom on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, zooming

Is it not possible to utilize the zoom already supported in the iPhone 4S-camera through some function calls like Android's `setzoom();` method?

Comment: Can someone please clarify my doubt? Even if it is possible through some private APIs also I would like to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Apple's documentation of the `UIImagePickerController`-class, it does not seem like you can programmatically utilise the native camera-zoom of the iPhone 4S. However, if the property `showsCameraControls` ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls)) is set to `true`, the user can still zoom natively by pinching with two fingers.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any private APIs that can do this either.